# Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $n^2 \not\equiv n\pmod 3$, then $n\not\equiv 0\pmod{3}$ and $ n \not\equiv 1\pmod{3}$. State and prove the converse.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $n^2 \not\equiv n\pmod 3$, then $n\not\equiv 0\pmod 3$ and $ n \not\equiv 1\pmod 3$. State and prove the converse.

So I know the converse statement is: If $n\not\equiv 0\pmod 3$ and $n\not \equiv 1\pmod 3$, then $n^2\not\equiv n\pmod 3$.

To solve the converse, first I thought to prove the contrapositive of the converse. I did: If $n^2\equiv n\pmod 3$, then $n\equiv 0\pmod 3$ or $n\equiv 1\pmod 3$.

From here we would write the proof:

Assume $n^2 \equiv n\pmod 3$. This means $3\mid n^2-n$. We can then write this as $n^2-n=3k$ for $k \in\mathbb{Z}$. So, $n=3k-n^2$.

I'm not sure if this is correct so far, but I know we need cases because of the or statement and I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: The forward direction verifies that $\,n\equiv 0,1\,$ are roots of $\,n(n-1)\,$ and the converse is that there are no other roots, i.e. $\,n\equiv 2\, $ is not a root.

Comment: Use `\pmod` to get the parenthetical modular symbol.

Comment: If $3|n^2-n$, then $3|n(n-1)$, so $3|n$ or $3|n-1$

Comment: It can fail for moduli not prime powers, e.g. $\bmod 6\!:\ x(x-1)\,$ has roots $\,x\equiv 3,4\,$ distinct from $\,0,1\ \ $

Comment: keep in mind *exactly* one and *only* one of the following must be true.  $x=0\pmod 3; x=1\pmod 3; x\pmod 2$.   So $[x\not\equiv 1\pmod 3$ and $x\not\equiv 0\pmod 3]\iff x\equiv 2\pod 3$.

Answer (score 1):

> keep in mind *exactly* one and *only* one of the following must be true.  $n=0\pmod 3; n=1\pmod 3; n\pmod 3$.   So $[n\not\equiv 1\pmod 3$ and $n\not\equiv 0\pmod 3]\iff n\equiv 2\pmod 3$.

So the converse is $n\not \equiv 0\pmod 3$ and $n\not \equiv 1\pmod 3 \implies n^2 \not \equiv n\pmod 3$.    And to prove it.

$n\not\equiv 1\pmod 3$ and $n\not\equiv 0\pmod 3$ implies $n \equiv 2\pmod 3$.

And $n^2 \equiv 2^2 \equiv 4\equiv 1 \not \equiv 1 \equiv n\pmod 3$.

That's it.

Comment: Why repeat was had already been said multiple times in comments on the question? (not to mention many prior answers, probably including some of your own).

Answer (score 0):

The converse is:

> If $n \not\equiv_3 1$ and $n \not \equiv_3 0$ then $n^2 \not \equiv_3 n$.

This is equivalent to

> If $n \equiv_3 2$ then  $n^2 \not \equiv_3 2$.

What is $2^2$ mod 3? Isn't $2^2 \equiv_3 1 \not =2$?

We do note that if $n \equiv_3 2$ then $n=3y+2$ for some integer $y$. But then $(3y+2)^2 = 9y^2+12y+4 \equiv_3 ?$

Answer (score 0):

You have $3|n^2-n$, and you wish to show that $n\equiv0$ or $1\pmod3$.

Well, since $3$ is prime, $3|n(n-1)$ means $3|n$ or $3|n-1$, by [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma).

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Eucld is great overkill here when there is only one possible counterexample $\,n\equiv 2\,$ that needs to be checked. But, of course, Euclid (or equivalent) is essential to prove the generalization from $3$ to *arbitrary* divisors.